# How to edit permission for user/group in a space through Java in confluence

Tags: java, confluence

I want to revoke some of the permissions for users and groups in a space through Java/Groovy script . I have tried to use `removeallpermission()` but that remove the user itself from permission `.removepermission` doesn't work directly.
I have already tried https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/Remove-a-user-s-space-permission-via-the-API-Confluence/qaq-p/534748 but this is not working .

Any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: Please add code or more context about what you're talking about.

Comment: As a last chance, you can try the ReST API of Confluence: https://developer.atlassian.com/server/confluence/confluence-server-rest-api/

Comment: @RobertReynolds: what i want to do is revoke some of the permission from individual users from space permissions.  I have tried to follow :https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/Remove-a-user-s-space-permission-via-the-API-Confluence/qaq-p/534748 but this is not working .